# is there a way to convert group chat username to chatid in telegram

Tags: telegram

I am curious if there's a way to convert telegram chat username (like @ smth) to chat id (a negative number) without joining or adding a bot there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser)?